# Unknown, or unavailable dependency for gespeaker, needing python!

Tags: python, dpkg, dependencies, espeak

Wanting gespeaker for ubuntu. So I managed to install Python2 in my Ubuntu 20.04 installation.

`sudo apt-get install python2`
`sudo python2 setup.py install`

Looks like no errors  -/

Still claims gespeaker has (unlisted) dependencies in software app and also in command-line

`sudo dpkg -i "gespeaker_0.8.6-1_all.deb"`

RESULTS:

```
sudo dpkg -i "gespeaker_0.8.6-1_all.deb"
Selecting previously unselected package gespeaker.        
(Reading database ... 197742 files and directories currently installed.)        
Preparing to unpack gespeaker_0.8.6-1_all.deb ...        
Unpacking gespeaker (0.8.6-1) ...        
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gespeaker:        
gespeaker depends on python-glade2; however:        
Package python-glade2 is not installed.        
gespeaker depends on python-gobject; however:        
Package python-gobject is not installed.        
gespeaker depends on python-gtk2; however:        
Package python-gtk2 is not installed.        
gespeaker depends on python-xdg; however:        
Package python-xdg is not installed.        
gespeaker depends on python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~); however:        
       
dpkg: error processing package gespeaker (--install):        
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured        
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...        
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...        
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...        
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...        
Errors were encountered while processing:        
gespeaker
```

`espeak "This is a test"`  runs fine in command-line. Gespeaker listed in GUI apps list, fails on startup. Had this issue last ubuntu, seems a python dependency?

UPDATE:

`sudo apt-get upgrade` resuts:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:        
 gespeaker : Depends: python-glade2 but it is not installable        
             Depends: python-gobject but it is not installed        
             Depends: python-gtk2 but it is not installable        
             Depends: python-xdg but it is not installed        
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
```

Comment: That is an old version of gspeaker, which depends on python2, which is not supported anymore. Use the latest source course, which uses python 3. https://github.com/muflone/gespeaker#installation

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you are trying to use GeSpeaker from [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gespeaker). This previous Ubuntu version had more Python 2 libraries. You still can get them installed on 20.04 LTS by manual downloading:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gespeaker/gespeaker_0.8.6-1_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus-python/python-dbus_1.2.6-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./gespeaker_0.8.6-1_all.deb ./python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-dbus_1.2.6-1_amd64.deb
```

and enjoy.